# Uncaught TypeError: $scope.getalb.push is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

### 1. I Want to insert two dimensional array in local storage.

---

2. I face an error Uncaught TypeError: $scope.getalb.push is not a function(…) in else part of condition.

```js
//app.js
var homeApp= angular.module("homeApp",['ngStorage']);


homeApp.controller("homeController",function($scope,$localStorage){

  $scope.myFun=function(){
            $scope.leads = document.homeForm.leads.value;
            $scope.email = document.homeForm.email.value;
            $scope.phone = document.homeForm.phone.value;

            $scope.referance = document.homeForm.referance.value;
            if ($scope.referance == "ByReferance") {
                    $scope.nameref = document.homeForm.nameref.value;
                };
            $scope.preftime = document.homeForm.preftime.value;            
            $scope.dataArra = [{"leads":$scope.leads , "email":$scope.email, 
                         "phone":$scope.phone, "referance":$scope.referance, 
                         "nameref":$scope.nameref, "preftime":$scope.preftime}];

            $scope.getalb =localStorage.getItem('Leads');

            if (!JSON.parse($scope.getalb)) {

                  localStorage.setItem('Leads', JSON.stringify($scope.dataArra));

                } else {
                 debugger
                  $scope.getalb = $scope.getalb.push($scope.dataArra);

                  $localStorage.setItem('Leads', JSON.stringify($scope.getalb));
                }
       }

});
```

Comment: Error on this Line $scope.getalb = $scope.getalb.push($scope.dataArra);

Comment: [{"leads":"aaa","email":"xxx@aaa.com","phone":"9898989898","referance":"ByReferance","nameref":"sss","preftime":"Afteroon"},{"leads":"bbb","email":"xxx@bbb.com","phone":"9898989898","referance":"ByReferance","nameref":"qqq","preftime":"Afteroon"}] This Is the format i want to push data.

Comment: `localStorage or $localStorage` make your choice.

Comment: localStorage  not $localStorage its done by mistake

Answer (score 2):

$scope.getalb is not an array.so u can not push into it.
if u want $scope.dataArra to $scope.getalb do

```
$scope.getalb=$scope.dataArra
```

Comment: $scope.getalb =localStorage.getItem('Leads'); On this line Arry of my local storage store in  $scope.getalb i want to append new array store in $scope.dataArra, $scope.dataArra is generated  by input fild

Comment: if i do as you tell me data are replaced not append